# How can I get a UIImage from GPUImage camera?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I know I can use the still camera's `capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter` method, but it gives a shutter click sound and I still have some processing to do so I don't want it to sound yet.

I tried using a filter's `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer` method, but that is always turning nil.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
_backgroundImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view insertSubview:_backgroundImageView atIndex:0];

_camera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
_camera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
filter.brightness = 0;

[_camera addTarget: filter];

[filter addTarget:_backgroundImageView];
[_camera startCameraCapture];
// processTimer is to periodically do processing on what's being shown on screen.
processTimer =[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(processImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:processTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];


-(void) processImage {
    [processTimer invalidate];

    UIImage *testImage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer]; // always nil

    [_camera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error) {

         // additional processing here ... don't want shutter sound yet.

    }];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use GPUImageVideoCamera and GPUImageView?

Comment: How do I get a UIImage from a GUPImageView then? I'm already using a GUPImageView for the _backgroundImageView

Comment: You can get UIImage from the latest filter before GPUImageView in chain by calling `- (UIImage *)imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` method. In your case: `[filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]`

Comment: Ok, I was using the old version of GPUImage :(

Comment: I think that it can not initialize in 0.25 sec. Try to increase this value or call `[filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer]` after something is shown in GPUImageView instance

Comment: This isn't recognized as a valid method. (prior comment deleted) I was going to just grab the image from the view, but it isn't working. I've increased the timer to 10 seconds and have the same issue with nil returned from imageFromCurrentFramebuffer

Comment: OK.. finally got an answer to the problem. I need to call  `useNextFrameForImageCapture` on the filter before calling `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer`. This sometimes still returns nil, but gets me what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. finally got an answer to the problem. I need to call useNextFrameForImageCapture on the filter before calling imageFromCurrentFramebuffer. This sometimes still returns nil, but gets me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get UIImage without shutter sound from any filter in chain by using method:

`- (UIImage *)imageFromCurrentFramebuffer`

of `GPUImageOutput` and it's subclasses: `GPUImageVideoCamera`, `GPUImageStillCamera`, `GPUImageFilter`, etc.

If your aim is to show viewport just use `GPUImageView` as the last item in filter chain.

Comment: That method is returning a nil for me.

Comment: try calling      [filter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
        [filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        
        UIImage *currentFilteredImage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];